# Keep Pagination in Tabs

Tags: pagination, tabs

Is there a way to have pagination on multiple tabs?

I have a page the has 5 tabs, each tab has filtered content from the same posts.  For example:

Tab 1 - All Posts.
Tab 2 - Posts with Keyword One.
Tab 3 - Posts with Keyword Two.

etc...

My problem is that I can't figure out how to use pagination on each tab and have the user be able to select the page on that tab and stay on that tab - it wants to go back to the first tab.

Comment: anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following extension to the `WP_Query` class.

The extension only takes your arguments as an array, rather than a string format.

You'll to add individual values for "page_link" for each of your tabs. This should just be a string ("tab1", "tab2" etc etc)

Then you'll need to use the `$my_query->next()` and `$my_query->prev()` to add page turning links to each tab.

[Code Also Here](https://gist.github.com/1237117)

```
  <?php
class MF_Query extends WP_Query{
    private $page_link = "page";

    function __construct(array $args){
        if(!array_key_exists('posts_per_page',$args)) $args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
        if(array_key_exists('page_link',$args)) $this->page_link['page_link'];

        $args['offset'] = (isset($_GET[$this->page_link])?($_GET[$this->page_link]-1)*$args['posts_per_page']:0);
        parent::query($args);
    }

    function next($link_text = "Next"){

            $curPage = intval((isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1));//Use 1 if $_GET['page'] not set

            $link = "<a href='".remove_post_vars(curPageURL());

            if($curPage<$this->max_num_pages){
                echo $link.$this->constructQuery($this->merge(array($this->page_link=>$curPage+1),$_GET))."'>".$link_text."</a>";
            } else {
                return false;
            }


    }
    function prev($link_text = "Previous"){

            $curPage = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1);//Use 1 if $_GET['page'] not set
            $link = "<a href='".remove_post_vars(curPageURL());
            if($curPage>1){
                echo $link.$this->constructQuery($this->merge(array($this->page_link=>$curPage-1),$_GET))."'>$link_text</a>";
            } else {
                return false;
            }


    }
    private function constructQuery(array $query){


        $url_ext = "?";
        foreach($query as $k => $v){
            $url_ext .=$k."=".$v."&amp;";
        }
        $url_ext = substr($url_ext, 0, -5);//chop last ampersand off


        return $url_ext;

    }
    private function merge($get, $put){
        //Get values from one array, and put them in another (overriding existing values if appropriate)
        foreach ($get as $k => $v){
                $put[$k]=$v;
        }
        return $put;

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I decided to use links with different templates instead of tabs.  But I might use this in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to return an array from paginate_links(), check the url for a fragment identifier then append that to your array before output.